# window.print in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Blazor and I've been trying to find if there's any `window.print()` equivalent in Blazor.
I wonder if there is any pre-made component/helper for this or do I need to create one from scratch?
I've already searched enough and can't find any.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no equivalent in blazor but you should consider adding a javascript file with a method with window.print(), reference it in index.html and call it with injected IJSRuntime.

Reference in index.html

```html
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Javascript file

```js
function printInvoke() {
    window.print();
}
```

Example in component

```cs
@page "/print"
@inject IJSRuntime Js

<h3>PrintTest</h3>

<button @onclick="Print"></button>

@code {
    private async Task Print()
    {
        await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("printInvoke");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I end up doing this earlier because I really can't find any.

Comment: Hey quick heads up, you actually get an infinite recursive call if you name the javascript function `print()` because it overwrites the `window.print()` to be  `print()`. Either way, great answer, it solved my problem.

Comment: It works, but using class="row" doesnt work. All rows are ordered vertically instead of horisontally. Anyone has a fix for this?

Comment: You can do `await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.print");` without the thunk